# Computing linear congruence - Euclidean algorithm

Tags: modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

I have the following linear congruence:

$$5037x \equiv 8 (mod 79)$$

how could I find the value of x?

If I were to use the Euclidean algorithm, wouldn't I find the multiplicative inverse of $5037 (mod 79)$? The algorithm though works for $5037x (mod 79) = 1$, is it the same for $8 (mod 79)$?

Comment: You do not need the inverse of $8$ because you multiply both sides of the congruence
with $5037^{-1} \pmod{79}$ and get $x\equiv 5037^{-1}\cdot 8\pmod{79}$.

Answer (score 2):

First, since we are working modulo $79$, we can reduce everything modulo $79$.
$$  5037 x \cong 8 \pmod{79}  $$
becomes
$$  60 x \cong 8 \pmod{79}  \text{.}  $$
Now I'll describe the intention and plan of what we are doing because you seem a little muddled on these things.  We wish we could divide $60$ from both sides of the congruence, but division isn't straightforward in modular arithmetic.  In fact, it is more useful to talk in terms of multiplication and to say:  We want a $u$ such that $u \cdot 60 \cong 1 \pmod{79}$ so that we may multiple both sides of our congruence by it to clear the coefficient on $x$, leaving $x$ alone on its side of the congruence.  Notice that this $u$ is playing the role of "$1/60$" in the system of residues modulo $79$.

How do we find this $u$?  We want a $u$ such that 
$$ u \cdot 60 \cong 1 \pmod{79}  $$
which is the same thing as we want a $u$ such that 
$$ u \cdot 60 + k \cdot 79 = 1  $$
for some integer $k$.  This should look like the results of the extended Euclidean algorithm.  One thing to check immediately:  Is this equation satisfiable?  We check this by computing $\gcd(60, 79) = 1$ and ensuring that it divides the right-hand side, which it does.  If we are smart, we kept the coefficients in the GCD computation so we could immediately write 
$$  -25 \cdot 60 + 19 \cdot 79 = 1  \text{.}  $$
This means we also get a solution when we check that a solution exists (if we do the extra side work for the extended Euclidean algorithm).  This equation says
$$  -25 \cdot 60 \cong 1 \pmod{79}  \text{,}  $$
so $u = -25 \cong 54$ is the $u$ we need.

So
$$ 54 \cdot 60 x \cong x \pmod{79} $$
and using this in the original equation, 
$$ x \cong 54 \cdot 60 x \cong 54 \cdot 5037 x \cong 54 \cdot 8 \cong 37 \pmod{79}  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Thank you! Just a question – before applying the Euclidean algorithm to $60x \equiv 8 (mod 79)$, can I simplify the linear congruence first and apply the algorithm to $15x = 2 (mod 79)$? I did, and got -15 instead of -25, it also appears to be correct.

Comment: Also, if I were to multiply the inverse ($-15 \equiv 64 (mod 79)$) by $15$ in $15x \equiv 2 (mod 79)$ I would get $12$ instead of the $2$ that I expected. Is there something I'm (clearly) missing?

Comment: The reduction you describe is valid when $\gcd(4,79) = 1$, which it is.

Comment: By using the extended Euclidean algorithm, we find $-21 \cdot 15 + 4 \cdot 79 = 1$, so the *multiplicative* inverse of $15$ is $-21 \cong 58 \pmod{79}$.  Beyond that, I don't understand the operation you are describing.  "Multiply the inverse": additive or multiplicative inverse? inverse of what?  It sounds as if you compute $15 \cdot -15 \cong 12 \pmod{79}$, but I don't know why you would do that, $-15$ isn't the *multiplicative* inverse of anything in sight...

Comment: The last step of Euclid's algorithm: $(4 \times 79) - (15 \times 21) = 1 \equiv 1 (mod 79)$ I considered $-15$ instead of $-21$... how do I recognise the one I need to use? Pretty sure this sounds beyond stupid. Also, I multiplied the "inverse" by $15$ and computed $mod 79$ of the result attempting to obtain the second term of the congruence as a further verification layer, is this what I should expect?

Comment: When computing the GCD of $15$ and $79$, you discover that $-21$ is the multiplicative inverse of $15$ modulo $79$.  So if you have $15x \cong \dots$, multiply through by $-21$ and if you have $21x \cong \dots$, multiply through by $-15$, to isolate $x$.  If we multiply $15 x \cong 2 \pmod{79}$ through by $-21$, we get $-21 \cdot 15 x \cong -315 x \cong (-4 \cdot 79 + 1)x \cong x \pmod{79}$ on the left and $-21 \cdot 2 \cong -42 \cong 37 \pmod{79}$, exactly as we did in the long answer above.